# Bootstrap Glyphicon different colors on different machines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a column of glyphicon pushpins that appear [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Ooo.png) on my own machine (Windows 7) and appear [red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se5jw.png) on another machine (Windows 10.) Both are using Chrome to view the page. The [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJsm5.png) and [css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yyOZ.png) are the same on both machines.

How should I make them both black by default?

Answer (score 1):

use CSS property

```
style="color:black;"
```